# Android - Run two threads at the same time

Tags: android, multithreading

i have a Question, first a part of my code.

```
        myThread thread1;
        myThread2 thread2;
        if (firstThread == null) {
            (thread1 = new myThread()).start();
            Toast.makeText(CreateService.this, "first thread started",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (secondThread== null) {
            (thread2 = new myThread2()).start();
            Toast.makeText(CreateService.this, "second thread started",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

My Question : 
Are the 2 Threads running know at the same time ? Or one after another ?
How would look a code where they are running at the same time ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793135/thread-deadlock-in-java-ee-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread runs in Parallel so if you creating more than two thread all will be run at same time, To know they are running at same time/ parallel Log the message from each thread like

From thread 1

```
for(int count=0; count < 100; count++)
    Log.d("Thread 1":"Count : "+count);
```

From thread 2

```
for(int count=0; count < 100; count++)
    Log.d("Thread 2":"Count : "+count);
```

Comment: How can your code prove the threads are running parallelly?I don't understand well.

Comment: When you find in Logcat you came to know messages printed from both thread are not in series like  Thread 1 >Thread 1 : Count : 0, Thread 1 : Count : 1.....  Thread 2 >Thread 2 : Count : 0, Thread 2 : Count : 1.....  if they are in series then it executing one after another if not then parallel

Comment: thanks,I thought the questioner is asking whether the threads are running at the same time in different CPU?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently in your Main Thread:

```
MAIN
```

You start thread1:

```
MAIN  
startsThread1 ->    THREAD1
Toast               thread 1 executes
```

You start thread2:

```
MAIN  
startsThread1 ->    THREAD1
Toast               thread 1 executes
startsThread2 ->                        -> THREAD2
Toast                                      thread 2 executes
```

Your Main Thread, thread1 and thread2 will be executed at the same time.
Your toasts will be shown while both of them execute, not afterwards, because you present the toast on the Main thread (which is by the way the only thread where you should do UI changes)